# camera.rotation.reorder in DeviceOrientationControls and VRControls

Tags: three.js

`examples/js/controls/DeviceOrientationControls.js` has this [line](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/controls/DeviceOrientationControls.js#L13)

`this.object.rotation.reorder( "YXZ" );'

In a 360 video player, I am recording camera.rotation angles(x->pitch, y->yaw, z->roll), without this line the values of them seem weird (not just the values are swapped like if the x->roll and z->pitch), when I apply this reorder(in MouseControls and VRControls), they become more sensible.

So what does this line really do? and why other controllers does not have it? Why it is not just an issue of swapping?